# Declare event and parameter within ES6 function

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

As the title suggests, I am somewhat unable to figure out the correct syntax for this function.

Currently, I have an event listener on a map that fires a function when the map is clicked as seen below:

```
map.on("click",(event)=>addMarker(event,parameter))
```

This is fine, but I want to combine the function fired into one complete function. I am aware it can be done such that I don't have to define the event outside of the `addMarker` function. Rather, I want to define the event within the `addMarker` function such that I only have the single function that is fired once the map is clicked.

Below is what I am trying to achieve (it's not the correct syntax):

```
map.on("click",addMarker(map))
```

and the addMarker function is:

```
const addMarker = (event) => (parameter) =>{
  new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
}
```

can anyone help with the proper syntax of the proposed addMarker function? When I do it this way I get the error `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading:"lng")"`

Comment: And why would you want to change that syntax? It's a function that returns a function that does something. Can you change the definition of `addMarker` function? Because if you can then you can do anything you want with it. Right now it has to accept function that returns a function.

Comment: It should be `(parameter) => (event) =>` and not the other way around (assuming you want `map` to be `parameter` and the argument `.on()` passes to its callback to be `event` (which it typically is)). Also, please consider updating your question title to something more searchable for future readers with the same question

Comment: @AbsoluteZero I plan on reusing the function in other parts of the code, thus I would rather have all the events/ params being handled in one block of code for easy debugging

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you for that. How do I edit the title of my post?

Comment: If you click [edit] under your post (or this link), you can edit it in the first textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
const addMarker = (event) => (parameter) =>{
  new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
}
```

Is (mostly) equivalent to:

```
function addMarker(event) {
  return function (parameter) {
     new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
  }
}
```

For the [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) to work correctly you want to have it this way:

```
function addMarker(parameter) {
  return function (event) {
     new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
  }
}
```

(The function binding `parameter` has to be the outer one.)
Translating that back to an arrow function results in:

```
const addMarker = (parameter) => (event) =>{
  new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `Function` to the event handler as a callback. So, you can swap the parameters in `addMarker` as follows. This way, you will define a function that returns a function in which the `parameter` variable will be fixed to `map` for that instance:

```
const addMarker = (parameter) => (event) =>{
  new mapboxgl.addMarker({}).setLngLat(coords).addTo(parameter)
}
```